# How to assign value to this function in java incompatible types

Tags: java, swing, awt

How to assign value to this function in Java incompatible types?

```
public class CustomerInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9083257536541L;
    protected String id;
    protected String searchkey;
    protected String taxid;
    protected String name;
    protected String postal;

    /** Creates a new instance of UserInfoBasic */
    public CustomerInfo(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.searchkey = null;
        this.taxid = null;
        this.name = null;
        this.postal = null;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }    

    public String getTaxid() {
        return taxid;
    }    

    public void setTaxid(String taxid) {
        this.taxid = taxid;
    }

    public String getSearchkey() {
        return searchkey;
    }

    public void setSearchkey(String searchkey) {
        this.searchkey = searchkey;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }   

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }   

    public void setPostal(String postal) {
        this.postal = postal;
    }    

    public String printTaxid() {
        return StringUtils.encodeXML(taxid);
    }

    public String printName() {
        return StringUtils.encodeXML(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }    
}

  private CustomerInfo selectedCustomer;

  public CustomerInfo getSelectedCustomer() {
        // construct a CustomerInfo from the data in your String

        return selectedCustomer;
    }


 private void jcmdOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

           selectedCustomer = (CustomerInfo) jListCustomers.getSelectedValue();
            //test code
            String testing  = m_jtxtName.getText();
              System.out.println("Now the selectedCustomer is dispayed!");
            System.out.println(selectedCustomer);
             System.out.println(testing);
       //test code
            dispose();       
        }
```

In the above shown code, I need the string testing value to be assigned to `selectedCustomer`. How can I assign the value? This is the error I get:

```
selectedCustomer = m_jtxtName.getText();

incompatible types
    required: CustomerInfo
    found:    String
```

Comment: Well yes... `selectedCustomer` is presumably a variable of type `CustomerInfo`. How do you want to create a `CustomerInfo` from a string?

Comment: You need to construct a `CustomerInfo` object from `m_jtxtName.getText();` which returns a `String`.

Comment: thats my question is there any alternate to assign to the selectCustomer

Answer (score 2):

You can't!!!

`selectedCustomer` is an object of type  `CustomerInfo`.

`m_jtxtName.getText()` returns a `String`

You can't assign a String to a CustomerInfo.

Probably you need to do something like:

```
int id = 1; //Or whatever new id you have.
String name = m_jtxtName.getText(); 
selectedCustomer = new CustomerInfo(name); //or whatever id you have.
selectedCustomer.setName(name);    //or whatever name you have.
```

EDIT:

Something is missing from your class. Either it needs setter methods (it has only getters now, so you can't set other properties as name etc) or it needs a constructor with four arguments like:

```
public CustomerInfo(String id, String searchKey, String taxid, String name, String postal) {
    this.id = id;
    this.searchKey = searchKey;
    // etc
```

In this case, you might have six jtextfields in your screen, so te user can fill all fields and the create the Customerinfo object by passing all parameters to the constructor.

Comment: can u tell any alternate to assign value to the `selectedCustomer`

Comment: but i need to create a `constructor CustomerInfo` ... if so how?

Comment: You don't need. A constructor for CustomerInfo is include in the class automatically. (Provided CustomerInfo  is a class and not an interface).

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do it by simply casting a String to a `CustomerInfo` object, but you could extend your `CustomerInfo` but you could try something like this:

```
public class CustomerInfo {
    [...]
    public static CustomerInfo createCustomerInfo(String data) {
        // construct a CustomerInfo from the data in your String

        return createdCustomerInfo;
    }
}
```

I don't know what data you have in that String so i can not give you an advice how to implement this. e.g. If it is the ID you could use this to retrieve the CustomerInfo from database or something like that.

Comment: i am just passing the firstname to the String

Comment: if that is enough to retrieve the correct CustomerInfo then go for it otherwise you should rethink the value of your Dropdown

Comment: i don't see the code of your `CustomerInfo` class. Nor do i see what data you have in your `jListCustomers`. So tell me what should i check

Comment: and have you figured out how to retrieve a CustomerInfo with just a customer#s first name?

Comment: then find out. no one else on SO can do this for you